# is there a magnitude to sin?

Tags: sin, law, judging-others

Some time back a public figure was arrested for pedophilia. On Youtube, I observed many very hateful comments directed at this individual.

Are the people who were passing judgement on the public figure and even myself were any better than him? For example, I used to copy in examinations even though I knew it wasn't right. I acted selfishly and in this singer's case he acted selfishly as well. The only difference I see between his sin and mine is that his sin harmed another and has had serious repercussions while mine affected only myself.

Some may say comparing sexual impurity and copying is ridiculous but is it really? We both broke the law. Why do people consider some sins horrific while routinely committing simple ones? Isn't it hypocrisy? Is there any magnitude attached to each and every sin?

Is there a magnitude to sin?

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, this question isn't a good fit for this site: we don't attempt to discover the truth, *per se*, but rather our goal is to objectively describe and learn what specific groups of Christians believe. If you'd like to narrow the question by asking for the biblical basis for a particular view, or for the view of a particular denomination, this question may be answerable.  When you get a chance, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: Here's a related question asking specifically for Protestant views: [Do Protestants believe that all sins are equal?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/41820/21576)  And here's one regarding Catholic viewpoints on different sins: [What is the biblical basis for venial and mortal sins?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/34310/21576)

Answer (score 0):

**is there a magnitude to sin?**

Yes,

> John 19:11  Jesus answered, Thou couldest have no power at all against
>   me, except it were given thee from above: therefore he that delivered
>   me unto thee hath the greater sin.